# Error: Failed to load plugin 'unicorn' declared in '.eslintrc.js': Cannot find module 'eslint/use-at-your-own-risk'

Tags: nuxt.js, eslint

Does someone know about this issue, I can not solved eslint issue.

`node version 16.20.0`
`nuxt2`

while I am trying to add ts to nuxtjs2 project. I got this problem.
Could someone help me out. I'll really appreciate it.

[image]